# Is it possible to listen to multiple TIbco EMS queues in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, tibco-ems

I am trying to create multiple queue receivers based on the `queueNames` from the database.
I have tried creating a `JpaRepository` and in `@Configuration` class `Autowired` it. But this approach is throwing error. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Note: I am using Spring Boot.

Answer (score 3):

In spring is only @JmsListener annotation but you can't change it dynamically.

There is only one way. You can get list of topics/queues from database and after that poll topics/queues in a loop.

Comment: Till now I did not find any solution on this, I assume this as the limitation.